# How to set autowidth of slides in jquery slick on first page load

Tags: jquery, slick.js

I'm using single slider of `slick` to display month on my page. But on the initial load of page, all slides merged together, but when I change the slide everything gets corrected. On Initial page load width of main `div`, and of slides are set to `0`, but when I change `slide`, width is automatically calculated.

Following is my slick code --

```
 $('.project_heading').slick({
     adaptiveHeight: false,
     speed: 1000,
     arrows: true,
     centerMode: true,
     init: 0
  });
```

And here is the screenshot attached -- 
[image: disrupted slick slider]
when I change slide
[image: when slide is changed]